# Universal link not performing action despite url being hit

Tags: ios, swift

I've successfully implemented universal links in to my app. The AASA is live on my website, and running the following command in my terminal successfully boots the app as expected:

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted https://websiteurl.com
```

Note - the url is different in practice.

For reference, this is my AASA structure:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "identifier.bundle_id",
        "paths": ["*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, my eventual aim with these universal links is to integrate it into an API which requires a redirect URI, where I send users back to the app.

As a result, I've created a ViewController, imaginatively called CallbackViewController. I will redirect users to this screen when the app is ready.

For now, I've introduced the following code into my AppDelegate file. The aim here is to print 'callback' when a universal link with the phrase 'callback' in is hit. However, when running the initial command in my terminal and adding /callback onto the end, nothing happens.

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
            let url = userActivity.webpageURL, let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
            return false
            }
        
        if (components.path.contains("callback")) {
            print("callback hit...")
        }
        return true
    }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in this function? I'm wondering if it's related to my AASA but unsure.

Thanks!

Comment: In the project configuration have you set the `Associated Domains` capability up? If not you'll need to add a new entry and specify the value like so: `applinks:websiteurl.com`

Comment: Yeah that’s all set up! Opening the link opens the app, it just doesn’t action my function I’ve put into the app delegate file.

Comment: Try using the validator to ensure the file is being served correctly just to be sure: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

Comment: I'd also make sure the file is served over https, the `applinks:` in the project don't contain `https://` and try opening the url from a real device from the notes app.